# How many simultaneous connection can I have on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: wordpress, connection, google-cloud-sql

I've a WordPress-based LMS (Learning Management System; e-Learning portal) instance installed on Google Cloud Platform (via Bitnami).

Previously, when I install LMS (Moodle or WP-based) on the usual shared hosting (ie. Hostgator), I'll encounter "mySQL database connection error" when a class of 30 students log in at the same time. I later realized shared hosting like Hostgator got a db connection limit of ie. 15.

So the question is - how many simultaneous connection does Google Cloud support? Or, how many students can the LMS which is installed on GCP support? 1000?

With Regards,
William

Comment: You should really ask here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/

Comment: The max number of concurrent connections for Cloud SQL is indicated in here: http://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing

Answer (score 1):

As pointed to by [Razvan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495918/how-many-simultaneous-connection-can-i-have-on-google-cloud-platform#comment49095529_30495918), the maximum number of concurrent connections for Cloud SQL instances can be found on the ['Pricing'](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing) documentation page. Currently, the range sits at 250 to 4000 depending on the tier of instance you choose.

Should you require concurrency beyond that range, you may want to consider using your own Compute Engine VMs hosting your own MySQL servers.